# Find a table containing a unique id of concrete column that is common for all tables in sqlite3 database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

All tables have "id" column, where each row contains an unique id for the whole database. Is there a simple way to find which table a concrete id belongs to?

Comment: No. Just use the obvious way.

Comment: @CL I don't know if it a joke, but saying "simple way" I mean not writing some 20-30 lines of code like in answers to "find a value in all database". So if it is not a joke, could you please elaborate a bit more on "obvious way"? - I wonder if you meant using UNION